# Sending Mixed String and bytes over TCP in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sockets

I have a TCP socket client sending requests to a server with an OutputStream. I need to send something like this example:

---

REQ OP filesize data

---

The server receive the information using in.readLine() and need to create a new .txt file with the data received.
My problem is that i used a split into tokens to analyse the information and i cant convert the "data" string over a byte array because i guess some bytes is lost.

**How can i send the data to the server in one line/command(because i need to mix String with Byte array) without losing any data?**

Comment: Is that a command the will be executed from an actual command line or just sent by a program over a TCP/IP connection?

Comment: The command will be handle by the server that need to create a .txt file with the same data received. But im losing bytes in the process and i cant create the file again

Comment: I don't really get the problem here. Why should bytes get lost when sending them?

Comment: the message that i send to the server is a String concatenated with a Byte Array (the data of the file). This is probably my problem...! Because in the server when i split the string received to convert the data into a new file, the data cant be converted back to write the new file. I tried to print the length of the byte array sended and the byte array receive and i noticed 1 byte missing

Comment: Depends on how you send the data, I'd guess, could you post some sample code?

Comment: If you send binary data, don't read it as text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) which allows you to send different types over a stream.

After you have initialized a Stream you can receive the data (with different types) on the Server using [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

Maybe that's not a One-Liner, but streams are not designed to have a "one-liner" of data.

Just send them using dataOutputStream.writeInt()/.write(bytes) or if you want to send a Stream writeUTF().

On the dataInputStream you need to use readInt()/.read(bytes) or readUTF() of course.

Edit: Using a TCP Stream verify that you dont "loose" data, since the connection will be closed if there's a byte-drop (not like UDP).